# How to handle errors using Knex.js

Tags: error-handling, promise, nestjs, knex.js

I am using nest.js with knex and try to make error handler for my application.
So I can update my data in database using this code:

```js
const updatedProject = await this.knex('projects')
  .update('name', body.name) // body.name id new name which come from frontend
  .where('id', id) // id also come from frotend and I compare this id and id in database
  .returning('*');
return updatedProject[0];
```

But if I try to update the project whith id which don't exist I have not any errors.
I try catch them by this way but this is didn't work

```js
const updatedProject = await this.knex('projects')
  .update('name', body.name)
  .where('id', id)
  .returning('*')
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
return updatedProject[0];
```

How can I create and catch error if reqest is wrong?

Comment: It depends on your DB, mysql for example allows you to update a record by none existing record. This means that it returns a success (not promise reject) and as a returning value it returns an object with `affectedRows` field, which will be 0 in this case

Comment: I use postgreSQL and if there error come empty array, but I think there exist some kind of custom errors

Comment: Updating a missing entry in db is a valid operation therefore, it is not an error.